# Update multiple Postgres timestamps

Tags: django, postgresql

I am attempting to update timestamps for 100s of objects in Postgres 12 using the following query:

```
UPDATE foo_bar AS c SET
created_at = c2.created_at
FROM (VALUES
    (101, '2021-09-27 14:54:00.0+00'),
    (153, '2021-06-02 14:54:00.0+00')
) as c2(id, created_at)
WHERE c.id = c2.id;
```

Where `created_at` represents a dateTimeField:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "created_at" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text
```

I have tried many variations of the created_at values to no avail. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: It seems Postgres has problems reading the datetime string. Have you tried the `ISO 8601` format? e.g. `2021-09-27T14:54:00.000+0000` or instead using a real DateTime object instad of a string?

Comment: Your value is cast to text, you have to explicitly cast it to a timestamp using CAST()

Comment: Cast the first value to a timestamp: `VALUES (101, '2021-09-27 14:54:00.0+00'::timestamptz), (....)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That worked! Feel free to add an answer if you'd like and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @a_horse_with_no_name for the answer. I had to cast the values as timestamps with timezones as shown below:

```
UPDATE foo_bar AS c SET
created_at = c2.created_at
FROM (VALUES
    (101, '2021-09-27 14:54:00.0+00::timestamptz'),
    (153, '2021-06-02 14:54:00.0+00::timestamptz')
) as c2(id, created_at)
WHERE c.id = c2.id;
```

Postgres docs explaining how casting works ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html)):

> A cast specifies how to perform a conversion between two data types

> By default, a cast can be invoked only by an explicit cast request, that is an explicit CAST(x AS typename) or x::typename construct.

Postgres docs explaining `timestamptz` ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)):

> timestamptz is accepted as an abbreviation for timestamp with time zone